# c# Regex Match Exact Word in String

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string of text

```
string a = "Not Approved;Review Not Required;Terminated;Draft";
string input = "Approved";
```

and my input is "Approved", and it still return me false(which is what i want), but if my input is "Terminated" it still return me false(which is wrong).

```
Regex.Match(a, input + @"^\b").Success

Regex.match(a,@"\b" + input + @"\b".Success
```

Both not working like what i'm looking for

Comment: What's your condition for `True` and `False` ?

Comment: Why are you using a regex and not just contains? `a.Contains(input)`? Assuming all you want is to check if input is present in a.

Comment: @Jacobr365 Because he wants "Approved" to not match "Not Approved"

Comment: @RB Ah,  misunderstood the question.

Comment: @Jacobr365: Actually contains should work fine, just use an old trick:  `(";" + a + ";").Contains(";" + input + ";")`.

Comment: Split with `;` and check if any element is `Approved`.

Comment: `a.Split(';').Any(p => p == input)`

Comment: There is nothing in your post that demonstrates what the difference is between true and false.

Comment: Is `a` hard-coded?  If so why not make it an array/list in the first place since that's what you are trying to represent?

Comment: @mellamokb why i didn't think of this trick!! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just modify the *regular expression* a bit? Check for `';'` not for `'\b'`

```
  string a = "Not Approved;Review Not Required;Terminated;Draft";
  string input = "Approved";

  // do not forget to Escape for arbitrary input
  // true for "Terminated", false for "Approved"
  Boolean result = Regex.IsMatch(a, @"(^|;)" + Regex.Escape(input) + @"($|;)");
```